# Texture gets blackness and whitelines added to it

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I've tried to add a Texture to my OpenGL Display. Rendering a texture like normal.

**Getting the Texture:**

```
try {
        mainTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(texturePath));
        width = mainTexture.getTextureWidth();
        height = mainTexture.getTextureHeight();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Rendering the Texture:**

```
mainTexture.bind();
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex2f(x + width,y);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(x + width,y + height);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(x,y + height);
    glEnd();
```

**Using this in Initilization code:**

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**This is the result of the code:**

The Texture/Image is 50x50 pixels, which is inside the Blue box, but the Texture is getting rendered until the White lines, with Black just before the lines. Can't find the reason why it's doing it. It should ONLY render the 50x50 pixels, which is the width and height of the image/texture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was some problem with images size/dimension not being a power of two...
Read this: http://factor-language.blogspot.com/2009/04/opengl-textures-and-power-of-two-size.html

Comment: Isn't there a fix for that? Or a method in Slick/OpenGL

Comment: Hmmm you can with some extensions, but I would stick to that requirement. Good luck with your game.

Comment: I see.. Think i'll try around with some tricks, but otherwise i will stick to the Power of two. Thanks